# fetch host value based on NULL value or number from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table as given below in order

1. OPABC
2. OPHOST

I want to fetch the  `CPU_ID` & `LOGIN_NAME` from the second table based on the `OPABC_JOB_NAME`, `JOB_NAME`, `OPABC_CYCLE_KEY`, `CYCLE_KEY` and `OPABC_JOB_REC` due to some of the cycle key as `NULL` I am getting incorrect values.

```
OPABC_JOB_NAME  OPABC_JOB_REC   OPABC_CYCLE_KEY
GENEXT  DAEMON  null
GENEXT  FULL1   1
GENEXT  FULL10  10
GENEXT  FULL11  11
GENEXT  FULL12  12
GENEXT  FULL13  13
GENEXT  FULL14  14
GENEXT  FULL15  15
GENEXT  FULL2   2
GENEXT  FULL3   3
GENEXT  FULL4   4
GENEXT  FULL5   5
GENEXT  FULL6   6
GENEXT  FULL7   7
GENEXT  FULL8   8
GENEXT  FULL9   9


 JOB_NAME   CYCLE_KEY   CPU_ID  LOGIN_NAME
GENEXT  1   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  10  sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  11  sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  12  sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  13  sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  14  sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  15  sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  2   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  3   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  4   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  5   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  6   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  7   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  8   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  9   sn25666 sbswrk6
GENEXT  null    sn25666 sbswrk6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `NVL` function while matching the `CYCLE_KEY`, which is common in both the tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OPABC_JOB_NAME,
                JOB_NAME,
                OPABC_CYCLE_KEY,
                CYCLE_KEY,
                OPABC_JOB_REC,
                CPU_ID,
                LOGIN_NAME
  FROM OPHOST OH, OPABC OB
 WHERE NVL(OH.CYCLE_KEY, 0) = NVL(OB.OPABC_CYCLE_KEY, 0)
```

This way on encountering `NULL` as `CYCLE_KEY`, 0 will be returned and you will get 16 rows.

Answer (score 0):

For ORACLE:

```
SELECT cpu_id, login_name
  FROM OPHOST
 WHERE (job_name, nvl(cycle_key, -1)) in (
        SELECT OPABC_JOB_NAME, nvl(OPABC_CYCLE_KEY, -1) FROM OPABC);
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT cpu_id, login_name
  FROM OPHOST
  LEFT JOIN OPABC ON job_name = OPABC_JOB_NAME
   AND coalesce(cycle_key, -1) = coalesce(OPABC_CYCLE_KEY, -1);
```